# The FirefoxDriver quit() error occurs when launching the FF for the 2nd time

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a scenario where in
1. Launch FireFox, Application url-Login and then do some action and Logout and close the FireFox.
2. Launch New FireFox, Application url-Login and then do some action.

```
 public class Commonmethod
 { 
    public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    public void login(){ 
    driver=new FirefoxDriver(); 
    driver.get("url"); driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsr")).sendKeys("userid"); 
    driver.findElement(By.id("pswd")).sendKeys("pswd"); 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='login']")).click();
   }

   public void Function1(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("---")).click();
   }
   public void Function2(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("---")).click();
   }

   public void logout(){
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("input[@name='logout']")).click();
    }
   }

 public class callingfunction
  { 
    @Test
    public void launch(){
       login();
       Function1();
       Logout();
       driver.quit();
       login();
       Function2();
    } }
```

Here in the above code after Function1() is completed ,logout and browser gets closed. And then new FF browser gets launched and login happens successfully.

But after that its failing and control is not entering to the Function2(),throwing error "The FireFoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called"

Kindly help me how to resolve it.
Thanks,

Comment: Where do you first declare your `driver` object? Does it use the `static` keyword?

Comment: And is that your code in order, or are you using Before and After methods too?

Comment: @Josh yes public static webDriver driver;                                                             yes code is in order, am not using before after methods.

Comment: I think `static` will be causing the issue, try removing that and see if your example now works.

Comment: i saw in some post for "The FireFoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called" 
 after 
 driver.quit();
driver=null;
 then launch new FF. But even this didnt work

Comment: When you are going second time try as : `driver = null;driver=new FirefoxDriver();`..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur this didnt work :(

Comment: Yes same exception..

Comment: Can you show us the code where you're declaring `driver` initially?

Comment: public class simpleTest {
 
 public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

 @Test
 public void launch(){
  
   driver=new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.get("url");
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsr")).sendKeys("userid");
   driver.findElement(By.id("pswd")).sendKeys("pswd");
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='login']")).click();

   f1=Function1();
   Logout();
   driver.quit();

Comment: global declaration public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: Why are you initializing it before `launch()` if your first line of `launch()` is `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` ?

Comment: @Josh I added a much clear code for y am using initializing it before login() method. Kindly have look to the latest code,that i have edited in my question